# Error while cloning an object inside a map function on a RDD

Tags: java, scala, serialization, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to develop some exotic transformation on a Spark `RDD`. In detail, inside a `map`, I am using `org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils` to clone a complex object.

Here is the code:

```
val rdd: RDD[A] = // Getting the rdd...
rdd.map(SerializationUtils.clone(_));
```

The class `A` is a Java class that obviously implements `Serializable`.

```
public class A implements Serializable {
    // Some cool stuff
}
```

When the above transformation is executed by Spark we obtain the error `org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: A`. Moreover, the error is encountered only when the code is executed on a cluster.

What the hell is going on?!

**EDIT**: it *works* using another tecnique to clone the objects. Then, It has to be some problem related to integration between Spark and the apache-common lib.

Comment: If the error only happens, when the code is executed on a cluster: Make sure that the jar containg the class of `A` and all of its dependencies are really submitted to the Spark cluster (spark-submit ... --jars ...)

Comment: The jar contains the class, beacuse A is used in other trasformations made prior to this one.

Comment: Hmm... the fact that `A` is used in other _transformations_ prior to this one does not necessarily mean that `A` is included in the jar-file. Since Spark does lazy evaluation plus a bunch of fancy optimizations, your code may not be evaluated in the way that you expect, so if you only have transformations (and no actions) before this piece of code, it might still be the first time `A` is evaluated. Hence, I would still recommend that you double check the jar-file to be absolutely sure that `A` is included...

Comment: Well, what I would to say is that the class A is used in another trasformation and on that RDD an action was called. It's the same RDD.

Comment: Please show the code (including the working transformation), and how you submit the job to the cluster.